# replacing character value based off of two other variables in R data frame

Tags: r

I have big data set where the first two columns look similar to this:

```
team year

Arizona 2006

Arizona 2006

Arizona 2011

Oregon 2011

Oklahoma 2008

Colorado 2005

Colorado 2005

Colorado 2011
```

I would like to create another variable of the conference the team is in based off of the team and year. I was thinking something like `if(data$team="Arizona|Oregon|Colorado" & year=2011){data$conf='Pac-12}` but that doesn't work because there are often multiple rows that have the team and year I'm looking for. Does this make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

perhaps you need `ifelse`?

```
teams <- c("Arizona", "Oregon", "Colorado")

data$conf <- ifelse(data$team %in%  teams & data$year == 2011,
                     "Pac-12", "something else")
```

---

*Edit*

You can change things by subsetting as @Simplefish has shown you if you don't want the `if`. Although your question does ask for `if`s.

The other way is to do all the changes at once so you dont overcopy the answers. You could nest your `if`s like:

```
ifelse(data$team %in%  teams & data$year == 2011,
       "Pac-12", ifelse(data$team %in% "Oklahoma" & data$year == 2008,
                 "second answer", "third answer"))
```

But with lots of conditions this is cumbersome so maybe you want:

```
reference <- matrix(c(rep("Pac-12",3),rep("third answer",4),
                     "Second Answer",rep("fourth answer",8)), 
                    4, 4, 
                    dimnames=list(c("Arizona","Oregon", "Colorado", "Oklahoma"), 
                                  c("2011","2008","2006","2005") )
                    )

#> reference
#         2011           2008            2006            2005           
#Arizona  "Pac-12"       "third answer"  "fourth answer" "fourth answer"
#Oregon   "Pac-12"       "third answer"  "fourth answer" "fourth answer"
#Colorado "Pac-12"       "third answer"  "fourth answer" "fourth answer"
#Oklahoma "third answer" "Second Answer" "fourth answer" "fourth answer"


data$conf <- with( data, reference [ cbind(team,year) ] )
#    > data
#      team year          conf
#1  Arizona 2006 fourth answer
#2  Arizona 2006 fourth answer
#3  Arizona 2011        Pac-12
#4   Oregon 2011        Pac-12
#5 Oklahoma 2008 Second Answer
#6 Colorado 2005 fourth answer
#7 Colorado 2005 fourth answer
#8 Colorado 2011        Pac-12
```

A final way would be to `merge` things using a data.frame version of reference.....I'm sure someone else might demonstrate this.

Comment: the only problem with this is that I need to add multiple conferences, so the else replaces others that I've already done.

Comment: Is there a way to have the else do nothing?

Comment: If I understand you're comment correctly; you'll need to replace the conditional in the ifelse statement to reflect what should be the parameters of each conference.

Comment: yes, so the ifelse works great to create one conference but when I create another then it will replace the one I previously created with the conditional from the most recently created. The multiple ifelse statements that were added will probably be the best solution for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do it via direct subsetting:

```
data$conf <- rep(NA,nrow(data))
data$conf[(data$team == 'Arizona' | data$team == 'Oregon' | data$team == 'Colorado') & data$year == 2011]='PAC-12'
```

Comment: +1 . You could still save your self much typing here by doing `data$conf[ data$team %in% c("Arizona", "Oregon", "Colorado") & data$year == 2011] <- "PAC-12" ` and also `data$conf <- NA`

Comment: FWIW I upvoted @user1317221_G's answer because I think it's better than mine.

Comment: yeah the NAs weren't actually replaced when I ran it either. Thanks @Simplefish